# How can I calculate a percentage of a number using Parity Ink?

Tags: rust, substrate, rust-ink

So my problem is, that I am trying to calculate a percentage for a share, but ink! doesn't support floating points and I have no clue on how I can get a non-floating value that UI will denominate for me later.

For an example, this code will not compile.

```
let total_amount: u128 = 250;
let share: u128 = 104;
let percentage = (share as f64 /total_amount as f64) * 100 as f64;
// percentage = 41.6
```

Is there anyway to get a non-floating value for the percentage so I can denominate the returned number to decimals in UI? Or is there any other solutions to my problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. As it is [your code compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=3e9c9124bdd82b462dc6c5442f3740a6).

Comment: General solution is to use a fixed point number instead. Please specify exactly which libraries etc you're using.

Comment: @Jmd it sounds like his environment does not support floating point operations.

Comment: As far as I know ink comiples to wasm and f64 are supported there.

Comment: math works at any fraction the same way. you could times it by 10000. get the decimal you want. do comparisons at that point and convert it where you need?
 Maybe you can show it as a string? unfortunately i don't know ink, and i'm not sure why it would dictate what you can and can't show.

Comment: https://use.ink/faq/
if you search for floating point, they say what i said. use the ratio you need. and then display it with the proper decimal point location. maybe it requires a display type of string? i'll try to dig a bit more

Answer (score 0):

Use integer math, but scale your number first:

```rust
let total_amount: u128 = 250;
let share: u128 = 104;
let share_percent = share * 100 / total_amount; // 41
```

or, if you want more decimals:

```rust
let share_fraction = share * 10000 / total_amount; // 4160
```

then format the number appropriatly on the frontend, for example if your contract returns per_10000, like in the second example, then (or use some formatting library of choice more likely):

```js
4160 / 100 + '%' // 41.6%
```

You might want to look into using `checked_mul/checked_div` or `saturating_mul/saturing_div` in your contract code instead of regular `* /` to make sure you control how your code handles boundary values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Now it lets me get my variable, but if I try to use it it will give an error after trying to build the contract.

"let total_amount: u128 = 250;
 let share: u128 = 104;
 let share_percent = share * 10000 / total_amount; //4160
 ink_env::debug_println!("{}", share_percent);'

When I try to compile I get this.

'ERROR: An unexpected panic function import was found in the contract Wasm.'
 
Any ideas on why I'm having this error?